# Problema con subida de imagen en XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

Estoy tratando de hacer un ejemplo de subir imagenes al servidor usando XAMPP usando el código que posteo a continuación. El problema me surge al ver que la imagen que subo (por ejemplo "prueba.jpg" no me aparece en la carpeta que designo (que es "uploadImagen" y que esta dentro del directorio de htdocs) sino que me aparece directamente en la carpeta "htdocs" de XAMPP con el siguiente nombre "uploadImagenprueba.jpg".

Hice un var_dump($carpeta_destino) que devuelve "C:/xampp/htdocs/uploadImagen" para comprobar que la ruta es correcta.

Las dudas que tengo son: ¿Por qué no se está guardando entonces la la imagen en dicha carpeta? ¿Y por qué se está concatenando el nombre del archivo al nombre de la carpeta al subirla?

```
<?php

$nombre_imagen=$_FILES['imagen']['name'];   

$carpeta_destino=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploadImagen';

var_dump($carpeta_destino);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],$carpeta_destino.$nombre_imagen);
```

Este es el formulario para subir la imagen:

```
<form action="subirImagenes.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</table>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="imagen">Imagen:</label></td>
<td><input type="file" name="imagen" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><input type="submit" value="Enviar"></td></tr></table>
</form>
```

Comment: En `$carpeta_destino.$nombre_imagen` no estás separando el nombre de la carpeta del nombre del archivo con `/` y es por eso que lo concatena y también es por eso que guarda la imagen en el directorio principal, Es como si escribieras: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploadImagenprueba.jpg`

Comment: Es cierto. He cambiado:
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],$carpeta_destino."/".$nombre_imagen);
y ahora funciona perfecto.